# Local notifications are not received

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification

I use the `flutter_local_notifications` package for local notifications, but when I create a local notification I have no errors, but the notification does not arrive on iOS even though I have enabled permission to receive notifications. What could be the reason for not receiving notifications?

**local notification**

```
static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _localNotificationPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings androidInit =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('notify_icon');
    DarwinInitializationSettings iosInit = DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestSoundPermission: false,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
      requestAlertPermission: false,
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (id, title, body, payload) => null,
    );

    InitializationSettings initSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: androidInit,
      iOS: iosInit,
    );

    await _localNotificationPlugin.initialize(initSettings);
  }

  // to show periodic notification at regular interval
  Future showPeriodicNotifications({
    required String title,
    required String body,
    required String payload,
    required int timestamp,
  }) async {
    final NotificationDetails details = await _notificationDetails();

    await _localNotificationPlugin.periodicallyShow(
      1,
      title,
      body,
      RepeatInterval.everyMinute,
      details,
      payload: payload,
    );
  }

  // to schedule a local notification
  Future showScheduleNotification({
    required String title,
    required String body,
    required String payload,
    required int timestamp,
  }) async {
    final NotificationDetails details = await _notificationDetails();
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();

    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    await _localNotificationPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      0,
      title,
      body,
      // tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 10)),
      tz.TZDateTime(
        tz.local,
        now.year,
        now.month,
        now.day,
        now.hour,
        now.minute,
        now.second,
      ).add(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
      details,
      androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      payload: payload,
    );

    print(
      tz.TZDateTime(
        tz.local,
        now.year,
        now.month,
        now.day,
        now.hour,
        now.minute,
        now.second,
      ).add(const Duration(seconds: 10)),
    );
  }

  Future<NotificationDetails> _notificationDetails() async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel_id',
      'channel_name',
      channelDescription: 'description',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.max,
    );

    const DarwinNotificationDetails iosNotificationDetails =
        DarwinNotificationDetails(
      presentAlert: true,
      presentBadge: true,
      presentSound: true,
    );

    return const NotificationDetails(
      android: androidNotificationDetails,
      iOS: iosNotificationDetails,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For iOS, you have to generate the certificate from your MAC, and then you have to upload this to your Apple developer account under your app permission while enabling the Push Notification feature. Also, you have to enable background notifications while generating the TestFlight or IPA file as well.

You can see [this](https://medium.com/@m1nori/ios-setup-of-push-notifications-flutter-firebase-775b0430140e) and [this](https://medium.com/@1998.singh.amarjit/firebase-notifications-flutter-local-notifications-a7d894dc60fe) articles which show the steps in detail. I hope it helps!

Comment: If I do not use push notifications, but local ones, do I also need to do these actions for them?

Comment: Yes, sir, you have to. That's a requirement from Apple, they match the signature of the certificates you have uploaded to their account and the machine you are generating the IPA or TF from. It has to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

add `matchDateTimeComponents` parameter in `_localNotificationPlugin.zonedSchedule` method

```
await _localNotificationPlugin.zonedSchedule(
  0,
  title,
  body,
  // tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 10)),
  tz.TZDateTime(
    tz.local,
    now.year,
    now.month,
    now.day,
    now.hour,
    now.minute,
    now.second,
  ).add(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
  details,
  androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
  uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
      UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
  payload: payload,
  matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.[YOUR_VALUE]
);
```